# I sent a transaction from Electrum to Trezor wallet - the transaction has disappeared and the fund taken

Tags: hack

Any help please??
I think I lost 0.7 btc

```
Transaction
d18f69c508d9dd5bb5a5038894a79a2c355100a6a185b8aac1df3494ed131e94
Summary
In Block    Unconfirmed
Total Input 0.6845923 BTC
Total Output    0.68444386 BTC
Fees    0.00014844 BTC
Details
d18f69c508d9dd5bb5a5038894a79a2c355100a6a185b8aac1df3494ed131e94 ⚠️
first seen Sun, 03 Jan 2021 03:54:26 UTC
➡ 1LLzrwBEHWsRHk5YLLTFY4w4BqdfbDLghm0.02577756 BTC
➡ 1LLzrwBEHWsRHk5YLLTFY4w4BqdfbDLghm0.00758608 BTC
➡ 1LLzrwBEHWsRHk5YLLTFY4w4BqdfbDLghm0.01485129 BTC
➡ 1LLzrwBEHWsRHk5YLLTFY4w4BqdfbDLghm0.00674268 BTC
➡ 1LLzrwBEHWsRHk5YLLTFY4w4BqdfbDLghm0.01514086 BTC
➡ 1LLzrwBEHWsRHk5YLLTFY4w4BqdfbDLghm0.01 BTC
➡ 1LLzrwBEHWsRHk5YLLTFY4w4BqdfbDLghm0.00816756 BTC
➡ 1LLzrwBEHWsRHk5YLLTFY4w4BqdfbDLghm0.00962341 BTC
➡ 1LLzrwBEHWsRHk5YLLTFY4w4BqdfbDLghm0.02080733 BTC
➡ 1LLzrwBEHWsRHk5YLLTFY4w4BqdfbDLghm0.02851153 BTC
➡ 1LLzrwBEHWsRHk5YLLTFY4w4BqdfbDLghm0.02640941 BTC
➡ 1LLzrwBEHWsRHk5YLLTFY4w4BqdfbDLghm0.018482 BTC
➡ 1LLzrwBEHWsRHk5YLLTFY4w4BqdfbDLghm0.01490001 BTC
➡ 1LLzrwBEHWsRHk5YLLTFY4w4BqdfbDLghm0.02437251 BTC
➡ 1LLzrwBEHWsRHk5YLLTFY4w4BqdfbDLghm0.00757503 BTC
➡ 1LLzrwBEHWsRHk5YLLTFY4w4BqdfbDLghm0.04133579 BTC
➡ 1LLzrwBEHWsRHk5YLLTFY4w4BqdfbDLghm0.00165945 BTC
➡ 1LLzrwBEHWsRHk5YLLTFY4w4BqdfbDLghm0.01234919 BTC
➡ 1LLzrwBEHWsRHk5YLLTFY4w4BqdfbDLghm0.01105445 BTC
➡ 1LLzrwBEHWsRHk5YLLTFY4w4BqdfbDLghm0.00809206 BTC
➡ 1LLzrwBEHWsRHk5YLLTFY4w4BqdfbDLghm0.02749301 BTC
➡ 1LLzrwBEHWsRHk5YLLTFY4w4BqdfbDLghm0.01243002 BTC
➡ 1LLzrwBEHWsRHk5YLLTFY4w4BqdfbDLghm0.01193373 BTC
➡ 1LLzrwBEHWsRHk5YLLTFY4w4BqdfbDLghm0.00977051 BTC
➡ 1LLzrwBEHWsRHk5YLLTFY4w4BqdfbDLghm0.00124668 BTC
➡ 1LLzrwBEHWsRHk5YLLTFY4w4BqdfbDLghm0.02964461 BTC
➡ 1LLzrwBEHWsRHk5YLLTFY4w4BqdfbDLghm0.0242969 BTC
➡ 1LLzrwBEHWsRHk5YLLTFY4w4BqdfbDLghm0.01011918 BTC
➡ 1LLzrwBEHWsRHk5YLLTFY4w4BqdfbDLghm0.01134724 BTC
➡ 1LLzrwBEHWsRHk5YLLTFY4w4BqdfbDLghm0.02825585 BTC
➡ 1LLzrwBEHWsRHk5YLLTFY4w4BqdfbDLghm0.00690033 BTC
➡ 1LLzrwBEHWsRHk5YLLTFY4w4BqdfbDLghm0.01524587 BTC
➡ 1LLzrwBEHWsRHk5YLLTFY4w4BqdfbDLghm0.00983011 BTC
➡ 1LLzrwBEHWsRHk5YLLTFY4w4BqdfbDLghm0.00729229 BTC
➡ 1LLzrwBEHWsRHk5YLLTFY4w4BqdfbDLghm0.01968774 BTC
➡ 1LLzrwBEHWsRHk5YLLTFY4w4BqdfbDLghm0.03067904 BTC
➡ 1LLzrwBEHWsRHk5YLLTFY4w4BqdfbDLghm0.01569381 BTC
➡ 1LLzrwBEHWsRHk5YLLTFY4w4BqdfbDLghm0.01044657 BTC
➡ 1LLzrwBEHWsRHk5YLLTFY4w4BqdfbDLghm0.0287376 BTC
➡ 1LLzrwBEHWsRHk5YLLTFY4w4BqdfbDLghm0.02337908 BTC
➡ 1LLzrwBEHWsRHk5YLLTFY4w4BqdfbDLghm0.03672393 BTC
36UjonxSP7xBwxvpQghVBGFpXNJqdLX9zS0.68444386 BTC ×
Fee: 0.00014844 BTC
UNCONFIRMED TRANSACTION!0.68444386 BTC
Raw Transaction
{
  "txid": "d18f69c508d9dd5bb5a5038894a79a2c355100a6a185b8aac1df3494ed131e94",
  "hash": "d18f69c508d9dd5bb5a5038894a79a2c355100a6a185b8aac1df3494ed131e94",
  "version": 2,
  "size": 7381,
  "vsize": 7381,
  "weight": 29524,
  "locktime": 664234,
 ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't find `d18f69c508d9dd5bb5a5038894a79a2c355100a6a185b8aac1df3494ed131e94` on any block explorer. It seems that you managed to redo the transaction with [`f1aa25811dd5487deb693a5bde124f674c2bf954de95df40bc23749f706b8968`](https://blockchair.com/bitcoin/transaction/f1aa25811dd5487deb693a5bde124f674c2bf954de95df40bc23749f706b8968), since it has a lot of similar input values.

In the transaction you posted, it seems that you created a raw transaction that didn't claim the change: all funds from inputs that are not assigned to outputs are transaction fee. After defining the recipient, you must claim all the remainder in a change output to yourself.

If you're experimenting with raw transactions or some new software you're writing,
I would emphatically recommend that you use testnet instead of actual Bitcoin.

Comment: All other transactions weren't me. The funds have been taken.
The transaction was generated from Electrum.

Either the private key got out or there is something bad about the initial transaction.

Comment: The initial transaction made it to the mempool but didn't get confirmed, and another one got there first.